# PageViewController in Swift, index keeps evaluating to nil

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I took one of the most popular online tutorial ( http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/ ) about making UIPageViewController with Storyboard and tried to convert it into Swift.

As one could expect, I encountered some issues.

Here is my code:

**PageContentViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
var pageIndex:Int!
var titleText:String!
var imageFile:String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageFile)
    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

@IBAction func startWalkthrough(sender: AnyObject) {
}
var pageViewController:UIPageViewController!
var pageTitles:Array<String>!
var pageImages:Array<String>!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.pageTitles = ["Over 200 Tips and Tricks", "Discover Hidden Features", "Bookmark Favorite Tip", "Free Regular Update"]
    self.pageImages = ["page1.png", "page2.png", "page3.png", "page4.png"]



    // Create page view controller

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    var startingViewController:PageContentViewController  = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)!
    var viewControllers:Array<PageContentViewController> = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return self.pageTitles.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}


//helper method to get the index of current page

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int)-> PageContentViewController?{

    if((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count))
    {
        return nil
    }

    var pageContentViewController: PageContentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index]
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index]
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

    return pageContentViewController

}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

    var index: Int? = PageContentViewController().pageIndex!
    if ((index! == 0) || index! == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        index! = index! - 1
        println(index!)
        return viewControllerAtIndex(index!)

    }
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    var index:Int? = PageContentViewController().pageIndex!

    println(index!)
    if (index! == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

    index! = index! + 1
    if(index! == self.pageTitles.count)
        {
        return nil
        }
    println(index!)
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index!)
}


}
```

Here are the issues:

1) When I run the app, it loads the first picture, but swiping right leads to runtime error which suggests that index of page is equal to nil. Then I tried to initialize index inside PageContentViewController

```
var pageIndex:Int! = 0
```

but this does not work. Index is not nil anymore, but whole logic of swiping right and left is down. It's counting only from 0 to 1 then gets back to 0 instead of incrementing to 2.

2) Second thing is that my label and button aren't visible, seems like they are covered by the picture, don't know why

If anybody got any idea about this index issue, I would be very grateful

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a local variable `pageViewController.pageIndex!` but static `PageContentViewController().pageIndex!` in delegate methods. This is why the `pageIndex` is always the same.

Here is how I did my implementation, so you can do something similar.

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> FeaturedRecipeViewController {
    let featuredRecipeViewController = FeaturedRecipeViewController(nibName: "FeaturedRecipeViewController", bundle: nil)
    featuredRecipeViewController.pageIndex = index
    return featuredRecipeViewController
}
```

Note here that I am setting an index to a ViewController object.

And when I'm looking for a next ViewController I do it like this:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let index = (viewController as! FeaturedRecipeViewController).pageIndex // This is the line you are looking for

    if index == pages.count - 1 {
        index = 0
    } else {
        index++
    }
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

I altered the code since it does something really weird in my case, but this should be similar to the thing you are looking for.

Comment: but pageViewController does not have a member called pageIndex….

Comment: in objective-c it was:
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

Comment: Well PageContentViewController is your class so only you know the implementation. My guess is from this Obj-C code that you should use something like this `((PageContentViewController) viewController).pageIndex`

Comment: Guess this is the issue, what the code in obj-c is really about. The line you wrote is incorrect and I have no idea what could be correct here:( Not only I know the implementation because the class is pasted in my post above :)

Comment: This Objective-C line does the following: It takes the viewController passed as an argument to the function, converts it to PageContentViewController, and then accesses it's pageIndex property.

Comment: What you tried to do in your question was access the _static_ property of the class which is identical for all of it's objects.

Comment: Alright I get it thanks! Nonetheless, do you know the correct implementation in Swift?

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I'll write out my implementation in Swift so you can see how I did it.

Comment: So my bad. This was the line you were looking for `(viewController as! PageContentViewController).pageIndex`

Comment: Thanks, awesome job! However, do you have any idea about the missing label and button, why are they hidden? my storyboard looks exactly the same as in tutorial mentioned at the top of my question

Comment: I can help you with that without more information. Best thing you can do right now I use view debugging in Xcode 6. Just run you app, navigate to that pageViewController and tap view debugging. You will then see if it's even loaded or where is it set (above or below some views).

Comment: Check this out http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/view-debugging-in-xcode-6--cms-22530

Comment: Thank you! I guess I shouldn't bother you anymore, I gonna make it! Thanks for help!:)